# Removing DateTime/Object from DatePeriod

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

I'm trying to create a filter, whereby if days (Monday, Tuesday etc) are NOT found in a list, I want that specific DateTime to be removed from my DatePeriod. This is so that I can say, I work Monday and Tuesday. If you find that the day is Thursday, continue out of this loop and don't include it.

However, I cannot seem to do this as when I iterate through a DatePeriod, I cannot unset anything, as it does not count it as an array. Is there a way to do this? The code can be found below:

```
//Get all the start and end dates of the holidays (This will be run iteratively)  
$get_st_date = $row['h_s_date'];
$get_end_date = $row['h_e_date'];
//Convert them to approprariate format to be used with DatePeriod   
$get_begin = new DateTime( "$get_st_date" );
$get_end = new DateTime( "$get_end_date");

//Add an extra day or else it will be omitted from the following process.
$get_end = $get_end->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
//Count per day
$get_interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$get_period = new DatePeriod($get_begin, $get_interval, $get_end);
//Iteration Count
$iter = 0;
foreach($get_period as $get_dt){
    //Find if date is  Saturday or Sunday. If it is, break that current loop.
    $iter++;
    $str_result = $get_dt->format('l');
    if($str_result == "Saturday") {continue;}
    elseif($str_result == "Sunday") {continue;}
    elseif(!preg_match("($str_result)", $e_d_w_p_w)){
        echo "<br>Don't count this day" . $str_result; 
        unset($get_period[$iter]); 
        continue;
    }
```

Then close the end tags (I haven't included it here as I do some other stuff.

From the above code, I get the following error:
"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type DatePeriod as array"

Is there a workaround to this?

For Clarification: $e_d_w_p_w is "Employee Days Worked Per Week"
$e_d_w_p_w is formatted like so "Monday;Tuesday;" etc

Comment: Is `$e_d_w_p_w` like a comma separated list of days in a string? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @ishegg Updated question to provide better clarify regarding $e_d_w_p_w.
"$e_d_w_p_w is formatted like so "Monday;Tuesday" etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.dateperiod.php) is *not* an array, just like the error says. It just has the properties required so as to make the list of days required, but it doesn't store them, so you can't `unset()` a specific day from the list.

What you can do to accomplish this is create a new array, and instead of removing the days that do not match the criteria from the `DatePeriod`, only add the days that do to this new array:

```
<?php
$get_st_date = "2017-09-01";
$get_end_date = "2017-09-20";
//Convert them to approprariate format to be used with DatePeriod   
$get_begin = new DateTime( "$get_st_date" );
$get_end = new DateTime( "$get_end_date");

//Add an extra day or else it will be omitted from the following process.
$get_end = $get_end->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
//Count per day
$get_interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$get_period = new DatePeriod($get_begin, $get_interval, $get_end);

$e_d_w_p_w = "Monday;Tuesday;";
$workDays = [];
//Iteration Count
$iter = 0;
foreach($get_period as $get_dt) {
    //Find if date is  Saturday or Sunday. If it is, break that current loop.
    $iter++;
    $str_result = $get_dt->format('l');
    if($str_result == "Saturday") {continue;}
    elseif($str_result == "Sunday") {continue;}
    elseif(preg_match("($str_result)", $e_d_w_p_w)){
        $workDays[] = $get_dt;
    }
}
var_dump($workDays);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/0TFE1)

Also, I think it might be a bit cleaner (and faster; avoid regular expressions whenever possible) to transform `$e_d_w_p_w` to an array and check if the current day is in that array:

```
$e_d_w_p_w = "Monday;Tuesday;";
$days = explode(";", $e_d_w_p_w); // transform to an array, separating by ;
array_pop($days); // remove the last element (assuming you always have a trailing ;
```

and then

```
elseif(in_array($str_result, $days)){
    $workDays[] = $get_dt;
}
```

Comment: this is a really awesome answer, definitely moving in the right direction! 

It turns out a lot of my code had to be rewritten to accommodate this solution in my real working example. However, your answer works for the situation I provided; and the only reason I knew where to rewrite my code was because of it. So thank you very much!

Comment: It's no problem! I'm glad you got it working. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I was researching ways to iterate over certain days within a DatePeriod and Google led me here. I ended up writing a class for it - hopefully this helps the OP.

[DatePeriod_Filter gist](https://gist.github.com/jmwebservices/fe317271e74c5f5f3a819b2c604053fd)

To address the OP needs, you may use it like so:

```
$e_d_w_p_w = "Monday;Tuesday;";

//Add an extra day or else it will be omitted from the following process.
$filter = new DatePeriod_Filter(
  new DateTime( '2017-09-01' ),
  new DateInterval( 'P1D' ),
  new DateTime( '2017-09-20 + 1 day' )
);

foreach( explode( ';', strtolower( trim( $e_d_w_p_w, ';' ) ) ) as $day )
  $filter->$day();

foreach( $filter as $date )
{
  // do something here
}
```